# Rails ISO8601 strip dashes, colon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, iso8601

In Rails 4 / Ruby, how can I return an alphanumeric string from an ISO timestamp?

`Time.now.getutc.iso8601 #=> 2015-10-08T16:12:51Z`

I'd like it to return the same as above without the `-` & without the `:`.
`#=> 20151008T121251Z`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) method to format your time in any way you please. It uses a String as a parameter which defines the output format.

In fact, the `iso8601` method uses `strftime` internally with `"%FT%T"` as a format string.

In order to get your desired output, you can use this format string:

```
Time.now.getutc.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
```

Please refer to the above linked documentation of the `strftime` method for a full list of available tokens.